# How to calculate rank from sql query and get that value in c# code behind

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `tbl_Generation`.
I have multiple columns in that table. Important one is `RGenerate` which is Boolean value having only 0 or 1 contained in that column and `EmpID(from tbl_Employee)`.
Tables are like this

```
 RGenerate    EmpCode
 0            101
 1            101
 0            101 
 1            201
 1            201
```

For example, here `EmpCode 101` has total count 1, for `EmpCode 201` it is 2.
I want to calculate rank for every user based on which user having highest RGenerate.
I am using SQL server 2012.

I want that rank for particular user on the code behind page.
Now I have an asp.net dashboard page where the user will see his rank.

How do I write the corresponding SQL query?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad in order to be answered. For instance, where do you want the caluclation being executed? At the database or at the application server? How many are the records in your table? Do you want your dashboard have a paging (not showing all results in one page)? etc. So I would first start with what I want to do and specify my first problem. For instance, I don't get how to write the SQL query, e.g. I tried this and it didn't work. etc.

Comment: "*How do I write sql query ?*" - so you want an SQL solution ? May I ask why the `c#` and `asp.net` tags ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window function and casting to write a SQL query that assigns rank to each user and then display it on your webpage

```
SELECT EmpCode, 
       row_number() over(order by sum(cast(RGenerate as int)) desc) rank
FROM tbl_Generation
GROUP BY EmpCode
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=181a661875daa24f42c0e5bfaadc43df)

Comment: This is a pretty valid answer regarding the SQL query part. However it is one of the many things that OP should address to get where he/she wants to. If the only issue is the SQL query, then this should be the answer that answers the question.

Comment: @Christos well, the only question I can see in the OP's post is *How do I write sql query??* so I believe this answers it :)

Comment: @Rafalon please spot the title _and get that value in c# code behind_. Then at the body of question OP refers to a dashboard. If for instance we have 100 `EmpCode` there are two options regarding this dashboard. Either we will show 100 `EmpCode` in one screen or we will show the first 10 (or another number of `EmpCode`). If we pick the latter approach, we have to make the paging. There are again two options, we might do this in database (my preffered way) or we could this in the application server. etc. So you see that there are more than one things.

Comment: @rchau If your only question is how to write the SQL query please edit your question and accept this answer as the correct one. Thanks

Comment: @Christos you're right, but I generally consider sentences without questionmark as context (he wants to do all this stuff, but he's stuck at "How do I write that sql query ?"). Hence, I can't figure out how an edit that removes the only question of a post can be approved...